# Autoscaling y axis to visible data in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have a time series waveform plot made with pyqtgraph. The user should be able to zoom in and out to various points in time (x-axis), and the y-axis should automatically scale to whatever data is visible within the current range of x values. I believe that `enableAutoRange` and `setAutoVisible` should allow this, but it doesn't seem to work. I have unlocked the aspect ratio but this doesn't seem to help.

A minimal example is below, please could anyone suggest how to get this working? Ideally when you zoom in to the low-amplitude data on the right hand side, the y-axis should scale up so that the sine wave is visble.

```
import numpy                   
import pyqtgraph               

x_data = numpy.linspace(0, 100, num=10000)
y_data = 1000*numpy.sin(x_data)           
y_data[5000:] = numpy.sin(x_data[5000:])  

plt = pyqtgraph.plot(x_data, y_data)      
plt.setMouseEnabled(x=True,y=False)       

vb = plt.getViewBox()                     
vb.setAspectLocked(lock=False)            
vb.setAutoVisible(y=1.0)                
vb.enableAutoRange(axis='y', enable=True)
```

One interesting thing is that if you zoom to the right hand side, and then right click and select Y-Axis>Auto, it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by setting the `enableAutoRange` and `setAutoVisible` every time the zoom changed.

It should look like this for your code:

```
def setYRange(self, (x_range_start, x_range_end)):
    self.enableAutoRange(axis='y')
    self.setAutoVisible(y=True)

vb.sigXRangeChanged.connect(setYRange)
```